# How to get the right order for creation of stored procedure, user-defined functions and triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I read that object dependencies have been improved in SQL server 2008.

I have a rather complex database schema containing stored procedure, user-defined functions, triggers.

Can anybody give me a query that would return the right order of creation of those items based on their dependencies ?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400920/is-there-a-tool-to-build-a-relationship-tree-of-the-stored-procedures-and-functio) that there are tools that can do the job, but I am looking for something scriptable. Also, they often give the dependencies of one object and I would like a database-wide solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment, because you probably already tried it, but.... If you right-click on the database and do Tasks/Generate Scripts, it will create a single script of all the database objects. But it cheats a little bit.

All of the tables are created with no foreign keys first. Then all the SPs are created. Then the foreign keys are added to the tables. So this doesn't really give you good dependency information.

It does, however, create the SP in a dependency-informed way, so there is some information to be gleaned from that.

Comment: In the above comment, I am, of course, referring to SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Redgate's sql compare pro can be executed via the command line.  I have the GUI version and it always gets things correct.  I've even learned a few things by looking at the output from this tool!

You can also use [SMO scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) to do it, but I believe you'll need to figure out dependencies and the proper order of operations for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did something based on that [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=277)

I modified the sp_FindDependencies to include the level in the dependency tree :

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_FindDependencies
 (
         @ObjectName SYSNAME,
         @ObjectType VARCHAR(5) = NULL
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @ObjectID AS BIGINT    

         SELECT TOP(1) @ObjectID = object_id
         FROM sys.objects
         WHERE name = @ObjectName
         AND type = ISNULL(@ObjectType, type)    

     SET NOCOUNT ON ;    

       WITH DependentObjectCTE (DependentObjectID, DependentObjectName, ReferencedObjectName, ReferencedObjectID, Level)
         AS
         (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                sd.object_id,
                OBJECT_NAME(sd.object_id),
                ReferencedObject = OBJECT_NAME(sd.referenced_major_id),
                ReferencedObjectID = sd.referenced_major_id,
                1 AS Level
         FROM    
                sys.sql_dependencies sd
                JOIN sys.objects so ON sd.referenced_major_id = so.object_id
         WHERE   
                sd.referenced_major_id = @ObjectID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
                sd.object_id,
                OBJECT_NAME(sd.object_id),
                OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id),
                object_id,
                Level + 1
         FROM    
                sys.sql_dependencies sd
             JOIN DependentObjectCTE do ON sd.referenced_major_id = do.DependentObjectID       
         WHERE
                sd.referenced_major_id <> sd.object_id     
         )
         SELECT DISTINCT
                DependentObjectName, Level
         FROM   
                DependentObjectCTE c
 END
GO
```

Then I walk through all the objects I want to track down. In my system, I maintain the version of those objects in a table SpVersion.

```
DECLARE @err int;
DECLARE @level int;
DECLARE @name varchar(50);
DECLARE @name2 varchar(50);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT SP.name AS obj_name
FROM sys.procedures SP, SpVersion SPV WHERE
SP.name = SPV.SpName
UNION
SELECT SO.name AS obj_name
FROM sys.objects SO, SpVersion SPV 
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%' AND SO.name=SPV.SpName
UNION
SELECT ST.name AS obj_name
FROM sys.triggers ST, SpVersion SPV 
WHERE ST.name=SPV.SpName;

CREATE TABLE #T1 (procname varchar(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, Level int);
CREATE TABLE #T2 (procname varchar(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, Level int);

OPEN cur
SELECT @err = @@error IF @err <> 0 RETURN  

WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name
    SELECT @err = @@error IF @err <> 0 RETURN 
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK

    DELETE #T1;
    INSERT #T1 (procname, level) VALUES (@name, 0);
    INSERT #T1 (procname, level) EXEC sp_FindDependencies @name;

    DECLARE cur2 CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT procname, level FROM #T1;

    OPEN cur2
    SELECT @err = @@error IF @err <> 0 RETURN  

    WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @name2, @level
        SELECT @err = @@error IF @err <> 0 RETURN 
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK

        PRINT @name;
        PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar, @level)

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #T2 WHERE procname = @name) BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #T2 (procname, level) VALUES (@name, @level);
        END ELSE BEGIN
            UPDATE #T2 SET level=@level WHERE procname=@name;
        END
    END

    CLOSE cur2;
    DEALLOCATE cur2;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

SELECT * FROM #T2 ORDER BY Level DESC;

DROP TABLE #T1
DROP TABLE #T2
GO
```